# XmlHttpRequest POST data is empty

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, post

I am trying to send data via AJAX to php by POST method. PHP code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

JavaScript code:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("POST", "test.php", false);
xml.send("a=X");
document.write(xml.responseText);
```

Result is:

```
Array ( )
```

Why isn´t in array [a] => "X"? Array is everytime empty. I am using PHP 5.6.3 on Apache 2.4.10 (XAMPP  v3.2.1).

Comment: what's `test.php` printing?

Comment: empty array `Array ( )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set the content type

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("POST", "test.php", false);
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml.send("a=X");
```

Comment: You have to call `setRequestHeader()` after `open()` but before `send()`